# Logging all traffic crossing SSH proxy

Tags: ssh, proxy, logging

Is there a way to log SSH sessions proxied through a machine (User-> SSH Proxy -> Server (with SSH)) without modifying the SSH daemon on the proxy? I need to log all the commands as well as responses exchanged between the User and the Server.

Comment: use tshark, install tshark on SSH Proxy and run this command: tshark -i eth0 -f "http" -w httpcapture.cap , it writes all the captured traffic to httpcapture.cap file which you can later easily analyse

Comment: Thanks for answering. I don't think that will work. Wireshark captures packet at the interface level (eth0) and encryption is done on application layer. The captured traffic will be encrypted.

Comment: If the machine is for you, so you have the ssh encryption key, and can decrypt it, I think.

Comment: Can you also elaborate what you mean by "modifying the SSH Daemon on the proxy"? Are you referring to editing the source code or making configuration changes?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you can do on the host, and what you man by without modifying the deamon. If you mean not recompiling openssh, then `ssh-mitm` might work for your use-case. Reconfigure sshd to listen on port 222, let ssh-mitm listen on port 22 with the same hostkey to proxy for port 222. Logs are written in /tmp

Ansible playbook and script:

```
---

- name: SSH Config
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  become: true
  vars:
    desired_state: present

  tasks:

    - name: Install Python libraries
      ansible.builtin.pip:
        name: ssh-mitm
        state: present
      no_log: true

    - name: Configure real SSH port in firewall
      ansible.posix.firewalld:
        port: '222/tcp'
        permanent: true
        state: enabled
        immediate: true

    - name: Configure SELinux for real SSH port
      community.general.seport:
        ports: '222'
        proto: "tcp"
        setype: "ssh_port_t"
        state: present

    - name: SSH port reconfiguration
      ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
        dest: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
        regexp: '^(#)?Port'
        line: "Port 222"
        state: present
      notify: Restart sshd

    - name: Copy mitm.sh
      when: desired_state == 'present'
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        src: mitm.sh
        dest: mitm.sh
        mode: '0700'

    - name: Run
      ansible.builtin.command: ./mitm.sh
      async: 0
      poll: 0
```

```
#!/bin/bash
systemctl restart sshd ; \
/usr/local/bin/ssh-mitm server \
  --listen-port 22 \
  --remote-host 127.0.0.1 \
  --remote-port 222 \
  --transparent \
  --host-key /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key \
  --host-key-algorithm ed25519 \
  --session-log-dir ~/tmp \
  --store-ssh-session \
  --store-scp-files
```

Comment: isn't that essentially modifying the SSH daemon?

Comment: The unmodified sshd binary is just listening on another port than expected, so just a bit modified, haha;-)